Looping over strings for use in document.evaluate() returns unexpected results
I am trying to reformat a webpage so that certain cells (td) are highlighted based on their values.  I have several labels I'm looking for, and wanted to try to do this in a loop.
The "label" seems to be correct in the console.log, but matchingElement doesn't get set to the correct element.  However, if I replace label with "Animal:", for example, in the document.evaluate() line, it works.  It doesn't seem to work when it's searching for the label when represented by a variable.  (No error, but it returns a matchingElement that doesn't contain the text I'm searching for.  I can't tell what it's searching on or why that matched.)
const labels = ["Animal:", "Human:"];

labels.forEach((label) => {
  console.log("Label: " + label);
  matchingElement = document.evaluate('//td[contains(text(), label)]/following-sibling::td', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  code = matchingElement.innerHTML;
  console.log("Code: " + code);
  if ( code == 10 || code == 30 ) {
    matchingElement.innerHTML = '<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">' + code + '</span>';
    console.log("Color green");
  } else {
    matchingElement.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">' + code + '</span>';
    console.log("Color red");
  }
});


Please [edit] your question to include sample of the relevant html.

You're not using the label variable for anything...?  (other than logging it to the console)

The label variable is not evaluated inside '//td[contains(text(), label)]. Use a template literal to substitute a variable into a string.

@Barmar:  Thanks!  I figured it was something like that but the solution was escaping me.

@David:  label is being used to create the document.evaluate() statement.

Answer based on suggestion from @Barmer:
const labels = ["Animal:", "Human:"];

labels.forEach((label) => {
  console.log("Label: " + label);
  matchingElement = document.evaluate('//td[contains(text(), "' + label +'")]/following-sibling::td', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  code = matchingElement.innerHTML;
  console.log("Code: " + code);
  if ( code == 10 || code == 30 ) {
    matchingElement.innerHTML = '<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">' + code + '</span>';
    console.log("Color green");
  } else {
    matchingElement.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">' + code + '</span>';
    console.log("Color red");
  }
});



